# Looking for simple way of representing database contents as filesystem (Windows)

Tags: java, networking

I have a Document Management System that stores documents in a database. I'm looking for a simple way (not too much and complicated protocol to implement) to show the database as a drive in windows (so it can be browsed and manipulated using any windows program, like explorer or office).

I have something in mind that I provide some kind of network share and that can be mounted as a drive in windows. Unfortunately all candidate network protocols for file sharing seem to require substantial effort to implement.

I first considered CIFS, but after reading up on that quickly decided that its *BY FAR* to complicated for me to implement. Next thougt was NFS, but its not supported by Windows (XP) natively and also seems quite complicated to implement.
FTP might be an option, but implementing an FTP server is again much more complicated than I naively expected.

There might be a simpler protocol to use I haven't thought of.

Is there anything I can (ab)use easily for this purpose?
Ideally I want some kind of (pure Java) premade server where I could easly strip out the part that accesses a local file system and replace it with my own code accessing the database OR a protocol simple enough that I can implement it myself reasonably quickly and more importantly, compatible and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make the correct bindings between your DBS and the database, and define/write an API in your program that will describe an easy access to the needed resources. Writing an API Will allow to maximize inter-operablity of your solution with other services or plugins you might want to add later.

After that, you should serve this services to clients through a permissive and robust protocol such as WebDav which stands for *Web-based Distributed Authoring and Versioning*. He is natively supported by Windows, you can this way interact with every services implementing WebDav (Windows, most web browsers ...), and you can of course also mount this kind of services as a virtual drive. Plus, it is also supported on Linux and MacOS X, I believe nativ'ely but i'm not sure. In fact, WebDav is an extension to HTTP, and is described in the RFC 4918.

Basically every HTTP (which handles server side response management) library for Java could be used to implement WebDav, if you havé some time and want to do it yourself.

To implement WebDav in a way and with an acceptable effort, I searched for some Java librairies on the web and found these ones, it's now up to you to decide which one really fits your needs :

- Milton http://milton.ettrema.com/index.html
- A list of some of the existing implementations of the WebDav protocol into open source projects on WebDAV.org (you can find there some pretty amazing projects such as The Jakarta Slide project although I think it is not supported anymore and other projects/librairies that shows the importance of WebDav today). http://www.webdav.org/projects/